# Program exported from processing 3.1.1 not working on android device

Tags: java, android, video, camera, processing

I have make a video player which split the monitor with one side the image captured by the attached camera and the other side a video clip. It operates without error under java mode. When I run the program under android mode, processing reports no error but the sketch is not running on my phone, a pop up window which says

> unfortunately, (sketch name) has stopped

shows up.

My code as below.

```
import processing.video.*;
Movie myMovie;
Capture cam;

void setup() {
size(displayWidth, displayHeight);
myMovie = new Movie(this,"new cctv.mp4");
myMovie.loop();
myMovie.mask(myMovie);

String[] cameras = Capture.list();

if (cameras.length == 0) {
println("There are no cameras available for capture.");
exit();
} else {
println("Available cameras:");
for (int i = 0; i < cameras.length; i++) {
  println(i,cameras[i]);
}

cam = new Capture(this,cameras[0]);
cam.start();
}
}

void draw() {
 if(cam.available()){
cam.read();}
image(cam, 0, 0, displayWidth, displayHeight);
image(myMovie, width/2, 0,displayWidth/2,displayHeight);
}
void movieEvent(Movie m){
m.read();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Time to start debugging your code.

The first thing you should try is hooking this up to LogCat so you can actually see the stack trace. Do that right now, as that's going to answer 95% of your question.

If that doesn't give you any information, then I guess you'll have to start adding print statements to see where your code fails.

I am suspicious of this line:

```
void setup() {
   size(displayWidth, displayHeight);
```

It's generally a bad idea to pass variables into the `size()` function, especially if you aren't using the [`settings()`](https://www.processing.org/reference/settings_.html) function.

I'm also suspicious of the libraries you're importing. Are you sure they work in Android mode? Not all Java libraries automatically work for Android.